# Access nested NSDictionary 10.8 SDK v 10.7 SDK

Tags: nsdictionary

I've written a method to access a nested dictionary stored in a plist. Works fine on the 10.8 compiler but I get the following error on the 10.7 compiler:

> Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object type 'NSDictionary*'

The plist has the following structure:

```
<dict>
<key>15.144.15</key>
<dict>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string>15</string>
    <key>X</key>
    <real>484.8828125</real>
    <key>Y</key>
    <real>104</real>
</dict>
<key>15.144.17</key>
<dict>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string>17</string>
    <key>X</key>
    <real>612.91796875</real>
    <key>Y</key>
    <real>190.6484375</real>
</dict>
</dict>
```

Here's the code I'm using to access the nested values for Message, X and Y:

```
NSString * value = [dictionaryFromPlist][parentKey][nestedKey];
```

I'm assuming that the 10.8 SDK handles accessing nested dictionaries in this way but 10.7 doesn't.

Anyone know a method that will be compatible with both SDKs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile with the 10.8 SDK and set your deployment target to 10.7. This is backward-deployable to 10.6. Your syntax is wrong, tho. Don't surround the variable name in brackets, just the subscript keys:

```
NSValue* value = dictionary[@"parentKey"][@"nestedKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, it was the deployment target that fixed my issue.

Comment: BTW the syntax is correct for how I am using it: [self methodToReturnDict][methodInputParameter][constant]

Comment: @Lymedo that's true, but that isn't what was in the code in the question, so I was just pointing it out.